# What software runs on a Azure PaaS server on a rack to make Java web apps work?

Tags: java, azure, paas

I guess it runs on some form of Windows Server 2012 but I wanted to know exactly what VMs & Azure Websites run on and what it takes to make Java web apps run on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This TechEd session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B384) has some great info on Java on Microsoft Azure. Java web applications can be run using a PaaS Worker role or on Azure Websites both of which have some form of Windows Server OS. This fact is supported by these screenshots which show a Windows file path within the metadata shown on a page hosted on Azure Websites and the Windows Server 2008 & 2012 TargetOS options shown within Eclipse configuration options. [image]
[image]

You may find this [Azure Friday video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-WebSites-Java-runs-great-in-Azure-) & [this MVA tutorial series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Java-on-Microsoft-Azure/01) helpful to learn more about Java on Azure PaaS

Answer (score 2):

Azure Websites (now called Azure Apps Service) includes Java 1.7.0_51 (32-bit) with a choice of containers, Tomcat 7.0.50 or Jetty 9.1.0. Web Apps also has a Web App Gallery where you can select Tomcat 7.0.52 or Jetty 9.1.2 if you want to customize the containers.

Java 8 isn't supported yet but the Apps team is working on it. Here are some great articles on Java support in Apps that are very helpful if you are new to running Java on the service.

[Create a Java web app in Azure App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/)

[Upload a custom Java website to Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/)

Answer (score 0):

You  may find in Azure portal that Java web app support switches off PHP, ASP.Net and Python one. It looks like they run Java web apps on dedicated server array (not Windows Server 2012). Actually I heard something like this on Azure DevCamp.